# MPI Matrix Multiplication Results

Tags: c, mpi

I am new to MPI and I am trying to multiply two matrices together. I seem to get the result for the first row but not for the second when I enter in a 2 x 2 matrix. I suspect that I am going somewhere wrong with matrix c calculation but I could be wrong. I am using mpi scatter and gather and I am not sure where I am going wrong with my logic, below is my code:

****Update****

so I updated my code and am now getting the correct result with one processor however when I increase the number of processors I get wrong values on the last two rows or basically get matrix A values on the last two rows. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

double *createMatrix(int n, int m)  // creates an empty matrix of size nxm
{
  double *matrix;
  matrix = malloc(m*n*sizeof(*matrix));

  for(int h = 0; h < m*n; h++)
    {
      matrix[h] = h + 1;
    }
  return matrix;
}

double *takeMatrix(int n, int m)  // takes in values from the user and creates a matrix of size nxm
{
  double *matrix;
  matrix = malloc(n*sizeof(*matrix));

  for(int h = 0; h < m*n; h++)
    {
      scanf("%lf", &matrix[h]);
    }
  return matrix;
}

void printMatrix(int n, double matrix[n][n])
{
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
      printf("%6.2f" , matrix[i][j]);
      printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // Define variables

  int id, p, np, ierr,  i, j, k;
  double time1, time2, time3;
  struct timeval start, end;
  long double execTime;

  MPI_Status status;

  ierr = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);     // MPI environment is initialized
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p); // Each process gets and unique ID (rank)
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);// Number of processes in communicator will be assigned to variable -> processCount
  
  int N;        // Allowing the user to enter in a matrix
  if(id == 0)   // Set the root process to be 0
    {
      scanf("%d", &N);
      printf("Matrix Size is: %dx%d\n", N, N);
    }


   MPI_Bcast(&N, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  // broadcast matrix size to all processors
   //MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);    // add a barrier so that all the processes are completed 

  double a[N][N], b[N][N], c[N][N]; // AxB = C // Matrix Holders
  double aa[N/p][N]/* ,bb[N/p][N] */, cc[N/p][N];

  // conventional one-processor solution

  void matmultcon()
{
  int i, j, k;
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    for(j=0;j<N;j++)
      for(k=0,c[i][j]=0.0; k<N; k++)
    c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][k] * b[k][j];
} // end conventional one-processor solution

/****************MASTER TASK*******************/
  if (id == 0)                                  // Matrix A is 2.0 and Matrix B is 3.0 for simplicity
  {
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
      {
      for (j=0; j<N; j++)
    {
      aa[i][j]= 2.0;
      b[i][j] = 3.0;
        }
      }
    // Print Matrix A
      printMatrix(N, aa);

    // Print Matrix B
       printMatrix(N, b);
  }

  
  time1 = MPI_Wtime(); // get time just before work section
  if(id == 0)
    {
       MPI_Scatter(a, N*N/p, MPI_INT, MPI_IN_PLACE, N*N/p, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
  else
    {
       MPI_Scatter(a, N*N/p, MPI_INT, aa, N*N/p, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
  // MPI_Scatter(bb, N*N/p, MPI_INT, bb, N*N/p, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Bcast(b, N*N, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  for(int i = 0; i < N/p; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
  {
    cc[i][j] = 0;
  }
}

/*****************WORKER SECTION*******************/
   // Start Timer

 gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    // Matrix multiplication
 if(id == 0)
   {
      for(int k = 0; k < N/p; k++)
       {
         for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
           {
         for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
           {
            cc[k][i] += aa[k][j] * b[j][i];
           }
           }
       }
   }

 else
   {
     for(i = 0; i < p; i++)
     {
        if(id == i)
        {
      for(int k = 0; k < N/p; k++)
       {
         for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
           {
         for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
           {
            cc[k][i] += aa[k][j] * b[j][i];
           }
           }
       }
    }
     }
       
   }
MPI_Gather(cc, N*N/p, MPI_INT, c, N*N/p, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

time2 = MPI_Wtime(); //get time just after work section
gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
execTime = (((end.tv_sec +  end.tv_usec) * 1e-9) + ((start.tv_sec + start.tv_usec) * 1e-9));
 

/**************************** END WORKER SECTION******************************/

 // Print the result matrix
  /* if(id == 0) */
  /*   { */
  /*    printf("\nResult matrix is as follows:  \n"); */
  /*     for(i = 0; i < N/p; i++) */
  /*      { */
  /*    for(j = 0; j < N; j++) */
  /*      printf("%6.2f  ", cc[i][j]); */
  /*      } */
  /*     printf("\n"); */
  /*   } */

 if(id == 0)
  {
    printMatrix(N, cc);
  }
   

  // run conventional 1-processor solution
  matmultcon();
  time3 = MPI_Wtime();

 printf("\nApproximate %d-processor time Tp: %f seconds \n",p,(time2-time1));
    printf("\nApproximate 1-processor conventional solution time T1: %f seconds \n", time3-time2);
    printf("\nUtilization Rate : %f\n",(time3-time2)/((time2-time1)*p));
    printf("\nExecution Time is = %Lf s \n", execTime);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

   MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: when computing `cc`, you should at the very least use `aa` instead of `a`.

Comment: Yup that helped thank you however my code only works on one processor is there a way I can make this work on n-processors using the MPI_Scatter and MPI_Gather?

Comment: There must be a way :-) the code you posted does not compile... please fix that first and I will have a look

Comment: So I reposted my code - I am using Linux Mint on a virtual machine, not sure if that matters, it is compiling there. Thanks!

Comment: defining `matmulcon()` in the middle of `main()` is not supported by my compiler, but anyway... There are several issues with your code. First, you need to scatter/gather/bcast `MPI_DOUBLE` since your matrix is `double[][]`. Forget the `MPI_IN_PLACE` thing, initialize `a` and scatter it into `aa`.

Comment: Then take a deep breath and refactor the Matrix multiplication part: `if (id==0) ... else for (i=0; i<p;i++) if (id == i)` looks like you thrown some code and hope it works.